# Google Apps from account for canned response

Tags: gmail, gmail-canned-response

Is there a way to change the “from” name/email address on a canned response auto responder?

I have one account setup with a nickname and a filter with a canned response (an ex employee), but when the canned response is sent, it comes from `currentuser+canned.response@domain.com`.

Is there any way to make it come from the regular nickname address?

Or even from the regular account address instead of the canned email address?

Answer (score -1):

Under *Settings* → *Accounts* → *Send mail as* → *When replying to a message* → *Reply from the same address the message was sent to*.

Under *Settings* → *Accounts* → *Send mail as* → edit info, you can change the name it is coming from.

It will still have canned response.

The alternative is to write a Google Apps Script to eliminate the special canned response email address.